# prevent scroll resetting after dom mainpulation

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I'm using an external plug-in that manipulate the DOM which in turn cause vertical scroll resetting on clicking

I know there is similar questions but non of them worked for me

I've tried handling it on 'change' but it never fired the event

```
$(document).on('change', '.element', myfunc);
```

The function absolutely have to remove and place element, there is no way to hide or change value, any suggestions are highly appreciated.

I did try to check hash anchor solution for tips and pointers but failed miserably, same thing with focus.

is there anyway to handle that resetting so I would prevent it?

Comment: You need to post more information than this if you hope to have someone answer your question. One function call is not enough for us to solve your issue, especially a function call that doesn't actually do anything. Please consult http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask questions that will attract answers.

Comment: that is a famous behavior of browsers, how my code will be relevant to this ?

Answer (score 0):

The **change** event is not for dom change. To catch insert event you can do this:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.element', myfunc);
```

I think you can use this for Insert and Remove both:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted remove', '.element', myfunc);
```